# C++ Win32 Change static Color

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to create label and change its background color and text color

i use this

```
HWND hwnder = CreateWindow(TEXT("static"), TEXT(text), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_LEFT, 10, 10, 50, 60, hwnd, (HMENU) NULL, NULL, NULL);
HDC hdcStatic = GetDC(hwnder);
SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(12,34,210));
SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(12,34,210));
```

the label get created but its color not getting changed, any way to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle the [WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787524(v=vs.85).aspx) message inside your `WndProc` function:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
{
    HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)wParam; // or obtain the static handle in some other way
    SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(255, 0, 0)); // text color
    SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(12,34,210));
    return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
}
break;
```

If you want to change only the specific component's color then obtain the target's handle using a simple `if` statement:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
{
    if (GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam) == IDC_STATIC1) // Target the specific component
    {
        // same as above
    }
}
break;
```

Comment: Hello, this change all static created, it is possible to change color only 1 Special static and let others or set different color for each?

Comment: @Vedbex I have updated the answer as per your input.

Comment: by the way it is possible to make this work for button GROUPBOX?